# Unable to run information.gain

Tags: r, information-gain, fselector

I am trying to run information.gain on 15 million data .The code I have used:

```
library(FSelector)

weights <- information.gain(is_opened~.,df)
```

but I am getting this error.

> Error in .jnew("java/lang/String", k) : 
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

How should I overcome this?

I tried to  use this code, still it didn't work:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8192m")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: I have already looked into this one...But it didn't solve my purpose.Could you  please help me out..